# New array of smaller size excluding one value from each column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

In Python 2.7 using numpy or by any means if I had an array of any size and wanted to excluded certain values and output the new array how would I do that? Here is What I would like

```
[(1,2,3),                                        
 (4,5,6), then exclude [4,2,9] to make the array[(1,5,3),
 (7,8,9)]                                        (7,8,6)]
```

I would always be excluding data the same length as the row length and always only one entry per column. [(1,5,3)] would be another example of data I would want to excluded. So every time  I loop the function it reduces the array row size by one. I would imagine I have to use a masked array or convert my mask to a masked array and subtract the two then maybe condense the output but I have no idea how. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Alfe actually gave me exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much guys I learned quite a bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude vector `e` from matrix `a`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)])
e = [4,2,9]
print np.array([ [ i for i in a.transpose()[j] if i != e[j] ]
    for j in range(len(e)) ]).transpose()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it very efficiently if you transform your 2-D array in an unraveled 1-D array. Then you repeat the array with the elements to be excluded, called `e` in order to do an element-wise comparison:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])
e = [1, 5, 3]    

ar = a.T.ravel()
er = np.repeat(e, a.shape[0])

ans = ar[er != ar].reshape(a.shape[1], a.shape[0]-1).T
```

But it will work if each element in `e` only matches one row of `a`.

---

EDIT:
as suggested by @Jaime, you can avoid the `ravel()` and get the same result doing directly:

```
ans = a.T[(a != e).T].reshape(a.shape[1], a.shape[0]-1).T
```

Comment: Won't broadcasting work its magic if you skip the unraveling and repeating and simply do `ans = a[a != e].reshape(a.shape[0]-1, a.shape[1])`? Nice approach, anyway.

Comment: @Jaime, nope. Try it -- the order gets garbled. The magic of broadcasting goes only so far! In this case, the irregularity of positions to be removed means that column lengths don't get preserved if you do it this way.

Comment: @SaulloCastro, strange, I tested it and it didn't work. I'll be interested to see what we did differently...

Comment: @senderle I've updated the answer... so you can check my approach

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. `(ans == a[a!=e].reshape(a.shape[0]-1, a.shape[1])).all()` returns `False`.

Comment: @senderle you are right... the results are not the same... I just rolled the answer back to rev. 1

Comment: @Jaime, unfortunately I did not manage to make the broadcasting rules work as in your example...

Comment: It works like a charm to get rid of columns though. So you can do something like `a.T[(a != b).T].reshape(a.shape[1], a.shape[0]-1).T` to have it work properly on rows. But it does lose some of the simplicity appeal, plus it returns a non-contiguous array, so not that great of an option.

Comment: It actually doesn't work properly... I get `[[4, 7, 2], [8, 6, 9]]` from running your code, and it should be `[[4, 2, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Jaime thank you... there was an error in the final reshape command, now it seems to be right

Comment: @Jaime, your approach returns a contiguous array, as well as mine, but contiguous along the column (Fortran)

Answer (score 1):

This would take some work to generalize, but here's something that can handle 2-d cases of the kind you describe. If passed unexpected input, this won't notice and will generate strange results, but it's at least a starting point:

```
def columnwise_compress(a, values):
    a_shape = a.shape
    a_trans_flat = a.transpose().reshape(-1)
    compressed = a_trans_flat[~numpy.in1d(a_trans_flat, values)]
    return compressed.reshape(a_shape[:-1] + ((a_shape[0] - 1),)).transpose()
```

Tested:

```
>>> columnwise_compress(numpy.arange(9).reshape(3, 3) + 1, [4, 2, 9])
array([[1, 5, 3],
       [7, 8, 6]])
>>> columnwise_compress(numpy.arange(9).reshape(3, 3) + 1, [1, 5, 3])
array([[4, 2, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

The difficulty is that you're asking for "compression" of a kind that `numpy.compress` doesn't do (removing different values for each column or row) *and* you're asking for compression along columns instead of rows. Compressing along rows is easier because it moves along the natural order of the values in memory; you might consider working with transposed arrays for that reason. If you want to do that, things become a bit simpler:

```
>>> a = numpy. array([[1, 4, 7],
...                   [2, 5, 8],
...                   [3, 6, 9]])
>>> a[~numpy.in1d(a, [4, 2, 9]).reshape(3, 3)].reshape(3, 2)
array([[1, 7],
       [5, 8],
       [3, 6]])
```

You'll still need to handle shape parameters intelligently if you do it this way, but it will still be simpler. Also, this assumes there are no duplicates in the original array; if there are, this could generate wrong results. [Saullo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18895167/577088)'s excellent answer partially avoids the problem, but any value-based approach isn't guaranteed to work unless you're certain that there aren't duplicate values in the columns.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of @SaulloCastro's answer, but handling multiple occurrences of items, you can remove the first occurrence on each column doing the following:

```
def delete_skew_row(a, b) :
    rows, cols = a.shape
    row_to_remove = np.argmax(a == b, axis=0)
    items_to_remove = np.ravel_multi_index((row_to_remove,
                                            np.arange(cols)),
                                           a.shape, order='F')
    ret = np.delete(a.T, items_to_remove)
    return np.ascontiguousarray(ret.reshape(cols,rows-1).T)

rows, cols = 5, 10
a = np.random.randint(100, size=(rows, cols))
b = np.random.randint(rows, size=(cols,))
b = a[b, np.arange(cols)]

>>> a
array([[50, 46, 85, 82, 27, 41, 45, 27, 17, 26],
       [92, 35, 14, 34, 48, 27, 63, 58, 14, 18],
       [90, 91, 39, 19, 90, 29, 67, 52, 68, 69],
       [10, 99, 33, 58, 46, 71, 43, 23, 58, 49],
       [92, 81, 64, 77, 61, 99, 40, 49, 49, 87]])
>>> b
array([92, 81, 14, 82, 46, 29, 67, 58, 14, 69])
>>> delete_skew_row(a, b)
array([[50, 46, 85, 34, 27, 41, 45, 27, 17, 26],
       [90, 35, 39, 19, 48, 27, 63, 52, 68, 18],
       [10, 91, 33, 58, 90, 71, 43, 23, 58, 49],
       [92, 99, 64, 77, 61, 99, 40, 49, 49, 87]])
```